# PANDAS date summarisation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'type':['Asset','Liability','Asset','Liability','Asset'],'Amount':[10,-10,20,-20,5],'Maturity Date':['2018-01-22','2018-02-22','2018-06-22','2019-06-22','2020-01-22']})
df
```

I want to aggregate the dates so it shows the first four quarters and then the year end. For the dataset above, I would expect:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'type':['Asset','Liability','Asset','Liability','Asset'],'Amount':[10,-10,20,-20,5],'Maturity Date':['2018-01-22','2018-02-22','2018-06-22','2019-06-22','2020-01-22'],'Mat Group':['1Q18','1Q18','2Q18','FY19','FY20']})
df1
```

right now I achieve this using a set of loc statements such as :

```
df.loc[(df['Maturity Date'] >'2018-01-01') & (df['Maturity Date'] <='2018-03-31'),'Mat Group']="1Q18"
df.loc[(df['Maturity Date'] >'2018-04-01') & (df['Maturity Date'] <='2018-06-30'),'Mat Group']="2Q18"
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve the same result? Perhaps have the buckets in a list and parse through the list so that the bucketing can be made more flexible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit specific. I would use.

- the `strftime` format `%y` to get the short
- the pandas built-in `quarter` to get the quarter
- the python `format` function to construct strings
- a `lambda` to `apply` it to the column

Here is the result. Maybe there is a better answer, but this one is pretty concise.

```
df['Mat Group'] = df['Maturity Date'].apply(
    lambda x: '{}Q{:%y}'.format(x.quarter, x) if x.year < 2019 
                                              else 'FY{:%y}'.format(x))
df

#    Amount Maturity Date       type Mat Group
# 0      10    2018-01-22      Asset      1Q18
# 1     -10    2018-02-22  Liability      1Q18
# 2      20    2018-06-22      Asset      2Q18
# 3     -20    2019-06-22  Liability      FY19
# 4       5    2020-01-22      Asset      FY20
```